# Maven Webjars - bootstrap-datepicker makes bootstrap invisible

Tags: maven, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker, webjars

I've tried to use Bootstrap and Bootstrap-Datepicker in my SpringMVC project:
[GitHub repo](https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Finager)

I trying to include both Bootstrap and Bootstrap-Datepicker via WebJars like this:

```
<!-- WebJars -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I comment out the bootstrap-datepicker dependency in pom.xml, the browser is throwing errors in the console like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/finager/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js 404 (Not Found)
```

This is working as expected. When I leave boostrap-datepicker section uncommented, the browser starts to see bootstrap-datepicker files, also as expected. Unfortunately, the browser console starts to throw similar errors saying that now Bootstrap files are not visible! It seems that boostrap-datepicker is somehow overriding Bootstrap.

I've tried to change my includes order and still the same effect. All of my .jsp files (CSS and JS includes) seem to be valid, because Bootstrap is visible when Maven does not try to include the datepicker. Is there a simple way to check what is visible in my webjars folder after compilation?

I am very confused. I couldn't find any useful information on the Internet. I've spent whole day on this, so any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the solution came up to my mind right after posting the question. It seems that Maven detected that bootstrap-datepicker was depending on bootstrap. I suppose that it included Bootstrap in different version in result - that would explain everything.

However, this is the solution:

```
<!-- WebJars -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
   </exclusions> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Is anybody aware of simple solution to browse /webjars directory structure after the Maven compilation? This would prevent such issues.

Comment: Kind of late but what you can do is build maven site lifecycle as

    mvn clean site

And then navigate to the build directory target/site and open the index.html

There you should see the all the dependency and included dependency as well.